# Complementary Encryption & Decryption functions between Oracle and .Net

Tags: .net, encryption, plsql, cryptography, tripledes

I'm looking for code that encrypts a string in Oracle PL/SQL using DBMS_CRYPTO and its matching decryption code in .Net framework. Both will need to use the same Key, IV and padding mode (where necessary). I'm not very verse in cryptography algorithms but if someone can provide the exact code for both sides i'd be very grateful... thanks!

My colleague is using the following code to encrypt a text "Test1234", the result of which is: **54AA98D8DE586F346E54B179AB71C6D7**

```
G_CHARACTER_SET VARCHAR2(10) := 'AL32UTF8';

G_STRING VARCHAR2(32) := '12345678901234567890123456789012';

G_KEY RAW(250) := utl_i18n.string_to_raw
                  ( data => G_STRING,
                    dst_charset => G_CHARACTER_SET );

G_ENCRYPTION_TYPE PLS_INTEGER := dbms_crypto.pad_zero
                                + dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes256 
                                + dbms_crypto.chain_cbc;


FUNCTION encryptSSN( p_ssn IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN RAW
IS

l_ssn RAW(32) := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW( p_ssn, G_CHARACTER_SET );

l_encrypted RAW(32);

BEGIN

l_encrypted := dbms_crypto.encrypt
               ( src => l_ssn,
                 typ => G_ENCRYPTION_TYPE,
                 key => G_KEY );

RETURN l_encrypted;

END encrypt_ssn;
```

In my .Net code, i tried this as a complementary function to encrypt the same way, but it gives me a totally different result!

```
public static string EncryptAES(string text)
    {
        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12345678901234567890123456789012");
        aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0123456789ABCDEF"); // Oracle's Default IV
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        // Convert string to byte array
        byte[] src = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

        // encryption
        using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);

            // Convert byte array to Base64 strings
            return Convert.ToBase64String(dest);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide Code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi @jasttim... i added some code for you above. Im sure there's something wrong in the approach. Feel free to give me a totally different solution if you have one. We just want to be able to encrypt a string in Oracle and Decrypt it in .Net, any secure algorithm will do.

Comment: @jasttim any idea?

Comment: Hi, I haven't had the time to review your recent updates, you could reach out to others though who should be able to assist you

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's default IV is NULL according to: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_crypto.htm#i1002112

.NET will not allow a NULL IV, so change the mode to ECB.

Modifying your code to the below returns the value expected as per your question:

```
public static string EncryptAES(string text)
        {
            AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12345678901234567890123456789012");
            //aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0123456789ABCDEF"); - Remove
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; // Change mode to ECB
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            // Convert string to byte array
            byte[] src = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

            // encryption
            using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);

                StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(dest.Length * 2);
                foreach (byte b in dest)
                    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
                Console.WriteLine(hex);

                return hex.ToString() ;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! However only with input text 16 characters and below, after that the encrypt output of both differ, is there a way to fix that? And also if you dont mind, can you provide the .Net decrypt function?

Comment: @TestBunch any feedback please...?